# Movq with strange offset

Tags: c, assembly, alignment, x86-64

I have two examples in c:

```
int main () {
    long i = 1;
}
```

and

```
int main () {
    int j = 1;
    long i = 1;
}
```

Here is asm code for both:

```
_main:                                  ## @main
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movl    $0, %eax
        movq    $1, -8(%rbp)
        popq    %rbp
        ret




_main:                                  ## @main
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movl    $0, %eax
    movl    $1, -4(%rbp)
    movq    $1, -16(%rbp)
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

Offset for `long` in first example is `-8`, but in second `-16`. Why do I get this `-16` and not `-12` (`sizeof long` + `sizeof int`)?

Comment: Alignment requirements.

Comment: Is there some general rule for this situation?

Comment: ok, found some tutorial on alignment http://www.songho.ca/misc/alignment/dataalign.html